Понятие "коллеции" и "объект-контейнер" в Python
В книге Т.Гэддис написано:"Словарь - это объект-контейнер, который хранит коллекцию данных". Подскажите, пожалуйста, понятие "объект-контейнер" как правильно понимать? Что представляет собой понятие "коллекция" в Python? В чем отличие между "коллекцией" и "переменной-контейнером"

Словарь это по сути список, элементами которого являются
другие списки. Сами элементы словаря - представляют собой кортежи из двух элементов (ключ, значение). Выглядит примерно так: [[], [], [('one', 1)], [], []]

@Amgarak "по сути" словарь - это вообще не список, это хэш-таблица. Вы слишком все упрощаете.

Объект-контейнер - просто объект, который может содержать (англ. contain), хранить в себе другие объекты. Коллекция тут не какой-то термин, а просто калька с английского, синоним набора данных. Типа "словарь - это объект, который хранит набор данных", что вообще ничего не объясняет. На самом деле смысл словаря в том, что в нем одним объектам (ключам) соответствуют другие объекты (значения). По ключу из словаря можно получить объект-значение, и наоборот по ключу в словарь можно записать какой-то объект. Как внутри это работает - почитайте вкратце про хэш-таблицы.

Что такое контейнер даже в чисто бытовом смысле? Это какая-то штука, которая может хранить в себе другие штуки. Также и в питоне - это просто объект, который умеет хранить внутри себя другие объекты питона.
А что такое коллекция? Это набор объектов с какими-то общими свойствами, каким-то образом систематизированный (иначе это будет просто свалка какая-то, а не коллекция). С точки зрения Питона коллекция - это опять же набор объектов (в какой-то степени однотипный, но не обязательно), который можно перебирать каким-то типовым образом.

Спасибо от Души. Немного прояснилось понимание. Спасибо Вам!
